# Location request does not appear after enabling in settings

Tags: permissions, request, location, swiftui

I am just starting out with SwiftUI and app development. In my app, I am checking for CLAuthorizationStatus. If the status is denied or restricted, I am showing an alert and guiding the user to the settings.

When the user selects to authorize always and goes back to the app, it works fine and gets geolocation.

But when the user selects "Never" or "Always ask" in the settings and returns to the app, I would like to force the app to reload and recheck for the permissions, because if the user selects "Always ask", the app should do exactly this, which it isn't. It stays ".notDetermined" in this case.

Here is some code from my LocationManager Class:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    .....

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

....
}
```

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.locationStatus = status

        switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                break
            case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
              if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                  self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }
            case .restricted, .denied:
                showPermissionAlert()
        default: break
        }

        print(#function, statusString)
    }
```

How can I manage to force a request on returning to the app? Quitting and restarting does bring the request window, but not returning from the settings.

Comment: How about in your .noDetermine case, add locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Comment: I think this is maybe a problem with the simulator... It works as intended (app is asking) on the iPhone SE and iPhone 8+ but not on the XS Max... Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is iOS version in XS Max?

Comment: it's version 13.2...